# Doesn't this contradict the contraction mapping theorem

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Consider this function $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ mapping from $[2, \infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then $[2, \infty)$ is a complete metric space. We also have $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$. However, there is no fixed point for this function.

Since $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$, I thought we could find $\alpha$ such that $0 < \alpha < 1$ by doing $\frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{ d(x,y) }$. The function is also mapping from a complete metric space. Why doesn't the contracting mapping theorem apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contracting mapping theorem applies if there is a constant $q \in [0,1)$ with $d(f(x),f(y))  \le q d(x,y)$. But no such $q$ exists !

Compute $d(f(x),f(y))/d(x,y)$ for $x \ne y$ and you will get $d(f(x),f(y))/d(x,y) \to 1$  for $x,y \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The contraction mapping theorem does not apply because its' assumptions are not met. The theorem requires the existence of a constant $C<1$ such that 
$$d(f(x), f(y) )<Cd(x,y)$$
Your example shows that $C=1$ won't do.

Comment: Can't I get a $C$ by doing $d(f(x),f(y))/d(x,y)$

Comment: @user1691278 Go on, find it. Can you?

Comment: @IvanNeretin You're saying that approach doesn't yield a constant but a variable that depends on x and y?

Comment: @user1691278 Sure you can find $C$. You'll get $C=1$. And that is not sufficient as I tried to point out.

Comment: @Thomas You're saying that C = 1 is the sup of $d(f(x),d(y))/d(x,y)$?

Comment: @user1691278 Why, the approach does yield a constant. Can you find it?

Comment: @user1691278 look at $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{|f(x+1) - f(x)|}{|x+1-x|}$